# Need help understanding RF radio parameters

Tags: rf, radio, bandwidth, fcc

I am experimenting with the SPSGRF-915 RF transceiver, particularly with the different center frequencies.

My question mainly revolves around the situation where multiple devices can transmit at the exact same time, and I need to make it possible for the respective receivers to decode the signals properly.

I plan to achieve this by modifying the center frequencies of each transmitter and receiver setup/pair so that each setup/pair can decode these signals properly.

If I were to configure transmitter A (TxA) and receiver A (RxA) to:

- Center Frequency: 913MHz
- Channel Space: 100kHz
- Bandwidth: 160kHz

and transmitter B (TxB) and receiver B (RxB) to:

- Center Frequency: 915MHz
- Channel Space: 100kHz
- Bandwidth: 160kHz

Would it be correct that these two setups should not interfere with each other because of the different frequencies and the bandwidth?

In the example above, since the bandwidth is 160kHz, would that mean that TxA would most likely occupy the 912.92 MHz to 913.08 MHz range, and this would not interfere with TxB because TxB would most likely occupy the 914.92MHz to 915.08MHz range?

What are other scenarios that could cause the setup above to fail?

Can a high transmit power (say +15dBm) on either transmitter cause the other setup to fail?

Comment: What is the characteristic of the filter that establishes the 160 kHz bandwidth?  All filters allow some energy/signal through outside of their specified cutoff frequencies.

Comment: @SteveSh The bandwidth of 160kHz is configured through software, but that bandwidth value itself was derived from the datarate. I'm not entirely sure, but I believe the bandwidth determines the frequency range that can be decoded by the receiver?

Comment: As you increase the TX power, there will be more energy at the edges of the frequency mask.  How much depends on how the system controls the bandwidth.

Comment: @SteveSh I should also add that the frequency deviation is 40kHz. I think this parameter is the parameter that determines the channel width?

Comment: @Aaron Could you explain what you mean by edges of frequency mask?

Comment: I also came across a term called harmonics, and from my understanding, any signal floating around could have some harmonics in adjacent frequencies. But this would not affect both setups as the harmonics appear at multiples of the frequencies?

Comment: Check the images here for frequency mask: http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/ads2004a/dgwlan/dgwlan02a6.html As the power is increased, the whole red trace will be lifted up. The blue line is the mask, what you need to stay under, in order for the system to not interfere with other systems.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you for sharing that resource with me. I was previously not aware that there are max/upper limits on how strong a signal can be. I'll read up more about this.

Comment: The American 915MHz band is tricky, because it has lots of rules about how you are allowed to send, regulated by something called FCC part 15. Simplified, this band requires that you jump around between a bunch of different frequencies according to a random sequence, never to return to a used channel before a lot of time has passed. Pre-made radios for this band typically features these things. Or alternatively, you can stay on one channel but reduce your output power dramatically, somewhere down to ~0.75mW ERP. For these reasons, your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Lundin Say if I were to not use frequency hopping, what would the maximum transmit power be in dBm units? If I were to not use frequency hopping, and I would transmit at fixed frequencies, would my max allowable transmit power be around -1dBm?

Comment: @Cimory You'll have to read Part 15 for yourself, it's available from FCC on the web. From what I remember, you can use lots of power if you use hopping. They may have channel width requirements though.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the clarification. I have been reading a bit about the FCC regulations on the 915MHz band, and I discovered that if I were to use only a single frequency, I should limit my Tx power to -1.25dBm. Since the SPSGRF-915 RF Transceiver is already FCC certified, does that mean that the radio already has this FHSS algorithm implemented?

Comment: @Cimory Yep that's the number I remembered too. But please note that it is "ERP", effective radiated power, the field strength a few meters from the antenna. Which is almost impossible to measure yourself, has to be done in a lab. But you can actually send out a bit higher power. I don't know how your specific part works.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the response! By any chance, do you have any resource to read more about the FHSS algorithm? I can't seem to find a simple example of frequency hopping between master and slave devices, and how they can agree/predict which center frequencies will be used in the following RF exchange. According to some sources, if I were to use FHSS, I could use the max transmit power, but I don't know how to manually implement that... Regarding the part, I'll try to look more about it and see if it has some frequency hopping implemented.

Comment: I think the only thing there is to know is that FCC states some minimum time (20 seconds?) that you must stay away before returning. I don't think it's important what algorithm you use for picking a new channel or how random it is. It's a rather stupid set of rules really, because the effective use of the band remains the same.

Comment: I don't remember the minimum time, but there were also rules regarding the channel spacings. Wouldn't the randomness affect the possibility of interferences with other devices? I had the thought that the FHSS algorithm would be similar to BLE's frequency hopping methods. How would the receiver also know which frequencies to use? And if the transmitter already hops frequencies but there are receivers that just turned on, how would the recently turned on receiver know which frequency to listen at?